# Compiler Error CS0119 - 'Case' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, winforms, variables

I am getting CS0119 error when trying to create 'case' variable of custom type Case in for loop.
line **Case case = new Case();**

```
private void cboSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = tableCollection[cboSheet.SelectedItem.ToString()];
        
        if (dt != null)
        {
            List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Case case = new Case();
                


            }
        }
    }
```

The error is going away when I rename the variable (to case1 for example).
Do you know why it's happening?

Case class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SLACasesImport
{
    public class Case
    {
        public string FacetsID { get; set; }
        public int Comp { get; set; }
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        public DateTime Opened { get; set; }
        public DateTime Closed { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActEnd { get; set; }
        public string Hosted { get; set; }
        public string Sustain { get; set; }
        public DateTime ImportDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `case` is a keyword. Try `@case`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message occurs because `case` is a keyword from `switch-case` statements. The nature of the message is that compiler / the IDE is expecting this to be within the context of a switch case statement since you're using the keyword.

If, for example, you tried to name the variable `int` you'd get `Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'SLACasesImport.Case' to 'int'`

Fun fact, you can even tell it's nature as a keyword in your example code because StackOverflow is highlighting it as such.

C# allows for special variable names like this when leading with an `@`. Like `@case` or `@int`. Though it is usually far more convenient to just use a different name altogether.

Comment: "Fun fact, you can even tell it's nature as a keyword in your example code because StackOverflow is highlighting it as such." This is just not true.  The code highlighting used by the site is a rough approximation, notably its inability to distinguish whether contextual keywords are in fact in a context in which they're a keyword or not.

Comment: @Servy that was the point of the comment though. Some languages don't mind if variable names are the same as keywords. C# isn't one of them. So StackOverflows inability to distinguish and highlighting `case` works here.

Comment: Many keywords *can* be used as variable names though, specifically contextual keywords.  If you have a variable named `async`, `await` , `get`, `group` they'll all work just fine, but SO will highlight them as keywords because it's not smart enough to realize they're not used in a context that makes them a keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am still learning C#. That is what I thought. But I expected VS would give me more specific error message=)